# AS3 Verify Socket Host Connection - Resolve Host?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, dns, host, resolve

I've ran into a bit of a problem where people are manipulating the connection of my game clients socket through the use of their local HOST file. That is to say, I have some method similar to

```
    private var _socket : Socket;
    public function init(host : String, port : uint = 0) : Boolean {
        _socket.connect(host, port);
        return true;
    }
```

I expect host to always be something along the lines of 'example.game.com', and for that to always resolve to some ip '255.255.255.255'. However through the use of HOST file it is possible that 'example.game.com' to resolve to '127.0.0.1', which is allowing for third party applications to intercept and modify game data.

The crooks of it are I cannot use DNSResolver as this requires AIR, the solution would have to be pure Actionscript. I also cannot trust a request to some external JS/PHP script that would resolve it for me, as the result of this could be modified with some HTTP Proxy (e.x. Fiddler)

Does anyone have any pure AS3 solution that would allow for me to ensure the host my socket has connected to is what I want?

Comment: I also up-voted the question, as it's a very good one that more people should be asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways.

Firstly, from initial testing it looks like you can query remoteHost and remotePort. Even if you're using hosts, they return a value that is useful to you. This is shown below.

Secondly, you can set up your socket to ping Flash in order to get a response every ~5 minutes or so. Have the ping request localAddress, localPort, remoteAddress and remotePort. If they do not match what you expect when you receive the data, terminate the connection.

Most importantly, validate on the server side whenever you receive data. Make your server aware of what the player is doing, as well as what is within reason. Mos multiplayer games (which is what I assume this is), effectively 'run' themselves on the server. So, if user A did manage to bypass the security you had set up and said he wanted to hit a target 5000 yards away for 1.5 million damage, the server already knows that:

- A he's out of range
- B he can't do that much damage

This topic is one of the most difficult to manage when it comes to developing the end game. Whilst you can battle it, and mostly win, you'll never stop people 'emulating' servers and using your content there. But, you should be able to stop most injections into your game.

**Edit**: Your problems really start when people begin to decompile the SWF and manage to recompile it. Then, any client-side validation is out of the window as they'll remove the validation that you have in place and you're reliant 100% on the server side validation. This can also happen through memory editing as well, though... In general, client side validation will only stop the more basic "hacker's".

```
package kazo 
{
    import flash.net.SharedObject;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.events.Event
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent
    /**
     * ...
     * @author KM
     */
    public class TestCases 
    {

        private var socket:Socket;

        private const ADDRESS_LIST:Vector.<String> = {
            '255.255.255.255',
            '255.255.255.254'
        }
        private const PORT_LIST:Vector.<String> = {
            '111',
            '112'
        }

        public function TestCases() { }

        /**
         * Start the test case
         */
        public function start():void {
            trace('Starting test case');

            socket = new Socket();

            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
            socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);

            socket.connect('example.domain.com', port);
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function onConnect(e:Event):void {
            trace(socket.remoteAddress);
            trace(socket.remotePort);

            // validate before doing anything
            validateNow();
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @param   e
         */
        private function onData(e:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace(e.target);

            // validate before processing data
            validateNow();
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        private function validateNow():void {
            var i:int = 0;
            // List of allowed ports (MUST be hardcoded)
            var portLen:int = PORT_LIST.length;
            // List of addresses (MUST be hardcoded)
            var addressLen:int = ADDRESS_LIST.length;

            var addressPass:Boolean;
            var portPass:Boolean;

            // Loop through, make sure we're valid
            for (i; i < portLen; i++) {
                PORT_LIST[i] === socket.remotePort ? portPass = true : continue;
            }

            // Loop through, make sure we're valid
            for (i = 0; i < addressLen; i++) {
                ADDRESS_LIST[i] === socket.remoteAddress ? addressPass = true : continue;
            }

            // If we're not, close off. If we are, run the course
            if (!addressPass || !portPass) {
                socket.close();
                // inform server
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You activated my trap card! This is a very detailed and well informed response to any body out there with a similar problem that can use the remoteAddress, remotePort methods. These methods are only available inside of an AIR runtime. My issue is that I cannot make use of these methods, thus the challenge becomes increasingly difficult!

Comment: Admittedly, my default setting is to export for AIR Captive Run time. That said, why the bloody hell they have made these 4 properties AIR only is beyond me. You're going to really struggle with this one in that case. My suggestion would be that on connection you send a variable, which is randomly assigned on each login, to the client. The client then has to respond with this variable each time it makes a request to your server. Generate the variable on the server side and only send it once you have a successful connection (and only once). That way, users can't _easily_ do this.

Comment: Basically, get creative with how you validate requests. Make it so that if somebody is emulating your server, they wouldn't be able to get one or two fields, without having firstly made a real connection. Then, change that variable for every single user. Store it in a DB and reset it to a new one each time a login request hits you. Validate all server calls against that variable which should already be assigned.

Comment: @DominicGunn I'd actually be interested to hear how you go about solving this one, and whether my advise was helpful or if you go down another route. It's an interesting topic.